# Prove that the image of the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ is the interval $[0,1)$

Tags: functions

I need a bit of help proving this. The understanding that I have is that if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, the image of $f$ is $f(\Bbb R)=\{f(x), x\in\Bbb R\}$. Is this correct? If so, where would I go from here?

This is the question:

> Prove that the image of the function
>   $$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$
>   is the interval $[0,1)$.

Any direction with respect to this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting. For future reference, how do I get that yellow box?

Comment: > at the start of a line, then type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider $ f(x)=y$ where $x\in R(domain) , y\in R(range) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=y\\ \Rightarrow x^2=y(1+x^2) \\ \Rightarrow x^2=y+yx^2 \\ \Rightarrow x^2-yx^2=y \\ \Rightarrow x^2(1-y)=y\\ \Rightarrow x^2=\frac{y}{1-y} \\ \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}} \in R  \;\; only \;\; when \frac{y}{1-y}\ge 0\;\; and\;\; y\ne 1 \\ hence\;\; y\in [o,1)$

Comment: Thank you. Can I use this approach for future problems like this? Or does it only work in this instance?

Comment: Yes you can use this for all problems

Answer (score 1):

Write $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=1-\frac1{1+x^2}$. The latter term has range $(0,1]$ since its denominator has range $[1,\infty)$. Thus the entire function's image is $[0,1)$.